# Azure policy - set "RequireInfrastructureEncryption" using "append"

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-storage-account

I am trying to create an Azure policy to set the RequireInfrastructureEncryption flag on new storage accounts. However, whenever I try to create a storage account programatically (PoSh), I get the error, `"The encryption service is missing from the request."`

The parameter "-RequireInfrastructureEncryption" is a switch parameter, so whenever I don't include it in the command below, the payload sent to the Resource Manager doesn't include the encryption property. So, the error makes sense.

But tbh, I don't see how the policy should look like in order to check whether the encryption property is present or not. And once that happens, the effect should, in theory, enable the infrastructure encryption.

Any suggestions?

```
New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName testrg -AccountName testsa -Location westeurope -SkuName Standard_GRS
```

```
"if": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    },
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption.requireInfrastructureEncryption",
          "notEquals": true
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption.requireInfrastructureEncryption",
          "exists": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"then": {
  "effect": "append",
  "details": [
    {
      "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption.requireInfrastructureEncryption",
      "value": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The parameter "-RequireInfrastructureEncryption" is a switch
> parameter, so whenever I don't include it in the command below, the
> payload sent to the Resource Manager doesn't include the encryption
> property. So, the error makes sense. But tbh, I don't see how the
> policy should look like in order to check whether the encryption
> property is present or not. And once that happens, the effect should,
> in theory, enable the infrastructure encryption.

***It is not possible to check and then enable the `-RequireInfrastructureEncryption` as it is a `read-only` property which can't be modified after the storage account has been created. That's why, You can set Effect the policy to `Audit` or `Deny` only.***

---

I tested the same by creating a Custom Policy with `DeployIfNotExists` effect like below :

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption.requireInfrastructureEncryption",
            "notEquals": "true"
          }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "name": "[field('name')]",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption.requireInfrastructureEncryption",
          "equals": "true"
        },
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/17d1049b-9a84-46fb-8f53-869881c3d3ab"
        ],
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "template": {
              "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "parameters": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "sku": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "location": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "kind": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "virtualnetworklist": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "metadata": {
                    "description": "The list of locations that can be specified when deploying resources"
                  },
                  "defaultValue": "test"
                }
              },
              "resources": [
                {
                  "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                  "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                  "properties": {
                      "encryption": {
                          "requireInfrastructureEncryption": "true"
                        }
                  },
                  "dependsOn": [],
                  "sku": {
                    "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
                  },
                  "kind": "[parameters('kind')]"
                }
              ]
            },
            "parameters": {
              "name": {
                "value": "[field('name')]"
              },
              "sku": {
                "value": "[field('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sku.name')]"
              },
              "location": {
                "value": "[field('location')]"
              },
              "kind": {
                "value": "[field('kind')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Then assigned the policy to a Resource group:

[image]

But the remediation task on existing storage account fails with the below error :

[image]

When I created a new storage account without infrastructure encryption enabled .It also resulted in same when the policy tried to update the parameter :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT, thanks for your comment. The idea was not checking whether I could append the value after the resource has been created, but the moment it is created. I know "RequireInfrastructureEncryption" is a read-only property that cannot be changed once the storage account has been created.

Comment: @Catalin, ok.. sorry for the confusion , then is the append not working for that requirement as well.

Comment: append should work .. let me try it as well

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. However, I don't believe it's possible. If there were a way to check if the encryption property is set or not, then I guess it could work, but I don't see a way to do it..
In my tests, I have tried something like below, but this is a type not a property on the storage account:
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryption",
          "exists": false
        }